# Visual Studio 2010 - Is there a plugin for customizing the compiler output?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, compiler-construction

Basically, our solution is composed of about 30 sub-projects.. and growing. Compiling this monster is fast and compiler warnings/errors/general output just scrolls by in a mishmash of ... well, poo. On unix it's easy to write a filter to "pretty-ify" the compiler output into something readable and, ultimately, useful.

Has anyone done this for VS2010? Something color coded as a minimum and one that would consolidate all the different projects would be ideal. Essentially, I'd love to have my compiler output displayed in a tree form with options to have all the children be closed unless there is a warning or error.

I also don't mind creating something for this or even having a macro that runs after the compiling is done that creates a more organized output of the whole mess.

Thanks in advance,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [vscommands 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf). It can colour the build/debug outputs and you can define your own formatting (warnings, errors, exceptions, code contracts ect.)